# How can I convert my date and time into an acceptable format for React Big Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime-format, react-big-calendar

I am taking date, start time and end time of an event from the database, all of which are stored as strings in these format: eventDate: "2022-02-21", startTime: "20:30", endTime: "22:30" respectively. I need to pass 2022-02-21 8:30 PM as the start time and 2022-02-21 10:30 PM as the end time. From the docs that I read, I believe I have to have them in the array list of event objects as:

new Date(2022, 2, 21, 20, 30, 0) and new Date(2022, 2, 21, 22, 30, 0). These values are dynamic, so I won't manually be able to change them. What are some ways I can manipulate the values of date, startTime and endTime to be able to pass it to the calendar?

Comment: So you're basically asking how to turn these strings into `2022, 2, 21, 20, 30, 0`? Did you try anything yet?

Comment: It's not exactly these strings. The values can be anything, but they are in these format. I am trying to split them up but I'm new to JS and react, so it's not working out.

Comment: This should do it: https://jsfiddle.net/kwmn0968/ (also, you should always put your attempt in the question so we can point out how to fix it)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const s = new Date(2022, 2, 21, 20, 30, 0), e = new Date(2022, 2, 21, 22, 30, 0)

const eventDate = `${s.getFullYear()}-${s.getMonth().toString().padStart(2, `0`)}-${s.getDate().toString().padStart(2, `0`)}`

const startTime = `${s.getHours().toString().padStart(2, `0`)}:${s.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, `0`)}`

const endTime = `${e.getHours().toString().padStart(2, `0`)}:${e.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, `0`)}`

console.log(`eventDate:`, eventDate, `startTime:`, startTime, `endTime:`, endTime)
```